# Linking SQL Server management studio to MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 10.5 and I'd like to link an Access file to it. I've been looking for answers over the internet but I didn't find any answers for this version.

I'm stuck at creating a new datasource (which should be the access file, right ?).

Where am I supposed to see the wizard for the creation of the datasource?

Comment: Use Control Panel> Administrative Tools> Data Sources (ODBC) to create a DSN

Comment: You cannot use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to log into MS Access directly.  SSMS is used to log into a SQLServer (such as SQL Server Express).  Once logged into a SQL Server you can connect that server to MS Access as a linked server or through open rowset, etc.  Then query from MS Access as a linked server or through the open rowset syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use DB Root tree-> Linked Servers -> Server Objects-> Linked Servers.

Don't forget to create a DSN to access to it from SSMS.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go on the "linked servers" part. Can you explain more please ?

Comment: You must have a jet provider. Pl. refer to the link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(SQL.80).aspx Still questions... feel free to PING.