# Connect SQL client to an MS Access database (instead of using MS Access SQL text editor)

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, sqlclient, squirrel-sql

Is there a way to connect an SQL client to query an MS Access database?

For example, with a Java-based SQL client like SQuirreL SQL, use a JDBC connection to query tables in an .accdb file.

---

**Use case:**

Complex SQL queries with multiple subqueries that are incompatible with the [Query Designer UI](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/design_view2007.php).

**Reason for wanting to use an SQL client:**

Using an SQL client would be much easier than writing SQL in the Access SQL window.

[image]

The Access SQL window is extremely limited:

- The text is small/hard to read and not mono-spaced
- There isn't any linting functionality, autocorrect, etc.
- The SQL spacing gets lost when you close a query and reopen it.
- No find & replace functionality.
- Many more limitations.

So, I'm hoping to find a way to connect an SQL client like SQuirrel to the Access database instead.

Comment: There are tons of SQL IDEs, most that support connecting to multiple RDBMSes support Access in some way, and some only support Access. I don't think a self-answered Q&A describing steps for a single product and using commercial software is a good fit here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking SQL Server management studio to MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009157/linking-sql-server-management-studio-to-ms-access)

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/51777/connect-to-an-ms-access-database-from-sql-management-studio

Comment: And also https://www.google.com/search?q=connect+to+ms+access+database+from+sql+server+management+studio+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

First:

> The text is small/hard to read and not mono-spaced

Go to *Files, Options, Object Designers, Query Design*, and set the font style and size.

> The SQL spacing gets lost when you close a query and reopen it.

No. But it gets lost if you go to design view and change anything.

> No find & replace functionality.

Go to *Home*, and the ribbon changes to include a *Search and Replace* option at right.

Next, though no fixed publishing date, the editor is going to be replaced with the *Monaco* editor known from Visual Studio Code.

Currently, I often copy-paste back and forth between the SQL editor and Visual Studio Code, indeed as SQL editor has no "revert" feature - you can only cancel changes to a previously saved query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is yes.

In SQuirreL, I used a JDBC product called CDATA Access JDBC Driver: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/access/jdbc/download/.

- It's a paid product, but it does have a free trial option.
- I installed the driver (via the .exe) and followed the instructions for using it in SQuirreL here: [Connect to Access Data in Squirrel SQL Client](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/access-jdbc-squirrel-sql.rst).

  - The instructions seem slightly incomplete, or at least out-of-date. But with a bit of *reading between the lines*, I was able to get it working.
  - Hint: Don't use this URL: `jdbc:access`. Use a full URL instead: `jdbc:access:DataSource=C:/MyDB.accdb;`.
- Related: [SQuirreL 4.5.1 wants a newer version of JVM, even though latest JDK installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74682853/squirrel-4-5-1-wants-a-newer-version-of-jvm-even-though-latest-jdk-installed)
- Initially, I was concerned about how legit the CData company was. Since I hadn't come acrross them before. But I see that they're listed on the [IBM Partners page](https://www-50.ibm.com/partnerworld/gsd/solutiondetails.do?solution=54021&lc=en&stateCd=P&tab=2). So I think they're probably safe.

---

**Result:**

I'm able to query my local .accdb MS Access database using the SQuirreL SQL client.

[image]

---

**Note about SQL syntax:**

The syntax seems to be generic SQL, such as SQL-92 or something like that. It doesn't use native MS Access syntax.

For example, this would work directly in MS Access:

```
where ucase(omi.p_commod) like '*MARBL*'
```

But in SQuirrel, the asterisk `*` wildcard isn't supported. Neither is the UCASE function. Instead, the percent symbol `%` wildcard is used. And UPPER is used instead of UCASE.

```
where upper(omi.p_commod) like '%MARBL%'
```

**Edit:**

It looks like RazorSQL might be another option (free trial; paid):

- https://razorsql.com/features/access_editor.html
- Screenshot of setup (very easy): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQwu2.png

And I suppose other SQL clients that support ODBC might be an option too, such as [Toad Data Point.](https://blog.toadworld.com/creating-odbc-connections-in-toad-data-point)

Or use SQL Server Management Studio: https://superuser.com/questions/51777/connect-to-an-ms-access-database-from-sql-management-studio. Although, I wasn't able to get that working.